# Program runs for forever but does not display anything

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class ConcreteClass
{
    private String fileName = "List.txt";
    private Customer[] clients = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {

        ConcreteClass first = new ConcreteClass();


        first.readFile();
        first.showCustomers();


        System.out.println("Hello World");

    }

    public void showIntro()
    {
        System.out.println("---------BANKING MANAGEMENT PROGRAM---------");
        System.out.println("1---Show list of customers.");
        System.out.println("2---Add a Customer bank account ");
        System.out.println("3---Remove a Customer bank account ");
        System.out.println("4---Sort customer list according to name");
        System.out.println("5---Sort customer list according to account balance");
    }

    public void readFile() throws Exception
    {   
        int index = 0;
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

        int count=0;

        while(reader.hasNextLine())
        {
            count++;
        }


        while(reader.hasNextLine())
        {
            String[] roster = reader.nextLine().split(",");

            String fName = roster[0];
            String lName = roster[1];
            String mName = roster[2];
            double balance = Double.parseDouble(roster[3]);
            String accNo = roster[4];

            Account b = new Account(balance,accNo);
            Customer c = new Customer(fName,lName,mName,b);

            clients = new Customer[count];
            clients[index++] = c;
        }

        reader.close();

    }

    public void showCustomers()
    {
        for(int i =0; i<clients.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(clients[i].toString());
        }
    }



}
```

---

```
Account(balance,account number)-toString(): ("Account Number: "+getNumber()+"/n Account Balance: "+getBalance())

Customer(fName,lName,mName,account)-toString(): ("Customer Name:"+getFirstName()+" "+getMidName()+" "+getLastName()+"  Customer Account:"+getAccount())
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your:

```java
while(reader.hasNextLine())
{
  count++;
}
```

you are just checking if reader has next line, but you are not going further. What I mean is imagine that you are at the first line, and you check if there is second line. Then in next iteration you are still on the first line. You need to go further, like this:

`reader.nextLine()`

Also, if you do that in your first `while` then your second `while` won't run, you need to take care of that some other way. And another thing - what you are doing with this array (clients) doesn't make sense, you need to create that array before those loops.

Answer (score 2):

This causes your code to run forever:

```
     while(reader.hasNextLine())
    {
        count++;
    }
```

You have to call reader.nextLine() inside, otherwise it is endless loop

Answer (score 1):

```
 while(reader.hasNextLine())
    {
        count++;
    }
```

You are never breaking out of this while loop. As a suggestion for the future if you are using the Eclipse environment then you can enter 'debug mode,' by setting a breakpoint (ctrl + shift + b) on any line of your code, then, after the program has halted on that line you can use f5-7 to navigate through your code.

I find this helpful when I become worried that my program has become stuck in some sort of loop somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Im not an expert but what executes first is the main method.

```
 ConcreteClass first = new ConcreteClass();
 first.readFile();
 first.showCustomers();
 System.out.println("Hello World");
```

This methods call other classes and methods afterwards.

At least you should get Hello World printed. (aside from the loop making the programm executing forever...preventing this to happen) Problem might be also the structure. You dont need such a long programm to print hello world either. A main method with a print should be enough.

Make sure you understand the concatenation of methods.